# Android - Set FrameLayout width dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a FrameLayout which I want to grow as time continues.

I've implemented a Runnable-Interface.

```
public void run() {
    time_value++;

    FrameLayout fl_dateTime = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.game_DateTime);
        LayoutParams lp_fl_dateTime = fl_dateTime.getLayoutParams();

    lp_fl_dateTime.width = time_value;

    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
}
```

Why doesn't this work? O_O

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the layout params back after modifying them.

[`View#setLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Comment: Also, make sure you're posting your runnable to the UI thread, UI operations from other threads are undefined or illegal or frowned upon or something. Looks like you're using Handlers though, so you probably are.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your Answer, it worked fine... Bought a book about Android developing and tried it out... And they never set the layout params back... so much thanks :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by setting the initial size of the frame to 0dp and then just setting the minWidth to whatever I wanted.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/black"
          android:id="@id/layout"
          android:minHeight="50dp"
          android:measureAllChildren="false">

item.setMinimumWidth(10dp);
```